# How to disable jupyter/ipython saving of intermediate (anonymous variables)?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

When you use Jupyter, you get these "numbered inputs & outputs" you can reference like this: `_3`. I'm the kind of guy who uses Jupyter like a nicer REPL with persistent code blocks & comments.
As time goes on, on long sessions, these kind of outputs start eating up memory, and then I have to restart the notebook and start all over.
I have NEVER in my life needed to reference these numbered variables (ok, maybe twice. Nothing I could not live without); so my question is: is there a way to disable them? Just to be clear: I still want to see my HTML-ified DataFrame, but I don't want the real df be saved into a variable named e.g. `_143`.

Comment: Does this work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69773053/how-to-cleanup-jupyters-background-variables

Comment: There is also a `reset_selective` https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-reset_selective which clears variables based on a regex...

Comment: reset magic might be the thing (although it'd be more ergonomic if it was a command line flag or something that worked like "fire & forget")

Comment: that may exist!